# Unable to download files from an Amazon S3 bucket to newly created EC2 instance using Boto3 ( passing UserData script as parameter)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3, putty

- I have written a python program using boto3 to launch a new instance and supplied startup script using UserData parameter as shown below ( '--' some id)

launchec2.py :

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.create_instances(ImageId='--', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, InstanceType = 't2.micro',KeyName='--',
SecurityGroupIds=['--'], UserData = open('startup_script.sh').read())

print(instances)

instance = instances[0]
instance.wait_until_running()
instance.load()
# printing dns name
print(instance.public_dns_name)
```

startup_script.sh :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os



os.system('sudo yum install -y python-pip')
os.system('sudo pip install boto3')


os.system('sudo yum -y update')
os.system('sudo yum install -y httpd')
os.system('sudo service httpd start')
# os.system('cd /var/www/html')


import boto3




access_id_key = ''
secret_access_key = ''
session_token_key = ''


s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id = access_id_key,aws_secret_access_key = secret_acces_key,aws_session_token = session_token_key)

my_bucket = s3.Bucket('cs351-lab2')
s3client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id = access_id_key,aws_secret_access_key = secret_access_key,aws_session_token = session_token_key)

for file_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(file_object.key,type(file_object.key))
    s3client.download_file('cs351-lab2',file_object.key,file_object.key)
```

- I have supplied every value like access id, secret key, and session token correctly. Now my problem is that the script is working perfectly fine up to os.system('sudo service httpd start')( when it is passed as **UserData**) and then it is not able to download files from
  s3 bucket.
- But if I run the script manually in that instance by command **"./startup_script.sh"** after creating **startup_script.sh** and enabling permissions to execute it, it is perfectly working fine and able to install all the files from the s3 bucket, but I am not sure why it is unable to download files when passed as UserData in launchec2.py.
- I am using putty.
- Can someone please let me know the solution? it would be of great help.

Comment: session token generally expires within an hour. How are you getting these credentials?

Comment: @NinadGaikwad actually I am getting it manually from vocareum, there we can find all details related to the account, so I am copy-pasting from there.

Comment: The `cloud-init` process that runs the User Data script has a log file in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` -- what does it contain?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

User Data scripts execute as the `root` user.

Therefore, **they should not use the `sudo` command**.

When you run it manually, you are running it as the `ec2-user`, which is a different environment.

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thanks for the answer, I was not knowing that the script is being executed by the root user and it is also working fine when I have used 'sudo'

Comment: In your question, you say "it is not able to download files from s3 bucket", but in your comment you say "it is also working fine". So, is it working, or is it _not_ working? If it is _not_ working, have you tried removing the `sudo` commands?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I have added os. system('cd home/ec2-user'), without this the file is being downloaded in the root directory ('/') ( which I was not expecting to download there), with that command I am able to download the file in 'ec2-user'. It's working fine now as I expected.